# Python: solvePnP( ) not enough values to unpack?

Tags: python, opencv, 3d-reconstruction, pose-estimation, opencv-solvepnp

I'm having problem with a function called `cv2.solvePnP` from OpenCV. This function is used to get a pose estimation of a chess board. After the following code I get an error:

```
for fname in glob.glob('Images/Calibragem/img1*.jpg'):
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (9,6), None)

    if ret==True:

        corners2=cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1), criteria)

        #finds the vectors of rotation and translation
        ret, rotationVectors, translationVectors, inliers = 
            cv2.solvePnP(objp, corners2, matrix, distortion)
        #projects the 3D points in the image

        imgpts,jac = cv2.projectPoints(axis,rotationVectors,translationVectors,matrix,distortion)

        imgAxis=drawAxis(img,corners2,imgpts)
        cv2.imshow('imgAxis', imgAxis)
        cv2.imwrite('imgAxis.png',imgAxis)
```

The error says:

> ret, rotationVectors, translationVectors, inliers = cv2.solvePnP(objp, corners2, matrix, distortion)
>   ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [opencv2 documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#bool%20solvePnP(InputArray%20objectPoints,%20InputArray%20imagePoints,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs,%20OutputArray%20rvec,%20OutputArray%20tvec,%20bool%20useExtrinsicGuess,%20int%20flags)):

```
 Python: cv2.solvePnP(objectPoints, imagePoints, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs[, rvec[, tvec[, useExtrinsicGuess[, flags]]]]) → retval, rvec, tvec¶
```

So there are only 3 values to unpack.
So you should be able to fix with:

```
ret, rotationVectors, translationVectors = 
            cv2.solvePnP(objp, corners2, matrix, distortion)
```

As solvePnP() only returns `retval`, `rvec` and `tvec`.

Comment: It's so strange. In the tutorial documentation there is this inliers variable that is used to receive the values of the function. But I worked the way you told me. Thanks peyo!